# Qt pro file call another makefile

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

Is there a way to use the .pro file in Qt to call another Makefile? For example, in a makefile, you could use:

```
make -f /other/path/Makefile
```

Is there anything like using the pro file for Qt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += other
PRE_TARGETDEPS += other
other.commands = make -f /other/path/Makefile
```

this will cause `make -f /other/path/Makefile` to be called as part of the make process, and will also give you the ability to type `make other` to just run that command.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to do it the other way around? Specifically to have automake read a Makefile.am file within which there is some command to build a .pro file so that the generated Makefile will then build the .pro file?